# Shared secret store / data structure for Java application

Tags: data-structures, keystore, shared, secret-key

I am designing a generic Java library which needs to Sign messages before Sending and Verify messages before accepting. Sign and Verify needs to work with both of the following constraints;

1. Use raw 32 characters long key with some additional details like key start date, end date, grace period, the algorithm as raw information (do not have a choice, but have to accept it as raw data).
2. Use a proper PKI certificate containing a public key

For PKI based secret it is straightforward to use [JKS/PKCS12](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1408345768-Different-types-of-keystore-in-Java----Overview) to store information and use it.

The problem I am facing is how do I manage and store raw information? What should be the data structure? So far my options are;

1. Use [JCEKS](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1420439432-Different-types-of-keystore-in-Java----JCEKS) provided by JRE to store all the raw information in my own made up data structure as secret properties and resolve at runtime to execute my library
2. Use [JKS/PKSC12](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1408345768-Different-types-of-keystore-in-Java----Overview) and along with X509 Certificate data structure to store all raw information under its Extensions

What I am really looking for is the best practices for these kinds of versatile requirements i.e. manage un-managed secret properties?